# OpenSSL issue on Debian server

Tags: php, openssl, debian

I've been battling this annoying issue for quite some time now, and it's bugging me a lot that I can't find any fix for it.

When I use "tail -f" to my `error_log` file to check for errors on my webserver, one specific error keeps popping up all the time, every visitor and page-refresh generates this issue.

I've been googling and searching here on Stack Overflow for a looong time, but nothing is directly related to the problem.

So the error that is thrown looks like this:

> [Fri Aug 17 00:16:23 2012] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] 
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/openssl.dll' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://mysite.dk/

What could I do?

I have tried to remove OpenSSL, and re-installed it again with no luck. I've tried to upgrade every PHP-related package and still didn't work.

```
grep -ir ssl /etc/php*
```

gives:

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/zend_extensions_psa.ini:extension=openssl.dll
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/zend_extensions_psa.ini:extension=openssl.dll
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.saved_by_psa.08.03;20:24:;extension=openssl.dll       ; moved to conf.d/zend_extensions_psa.ini by Plesk
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:;extension=openssl.dll        ; moved to conf.d/zend_extensions_psa.ini by Plesk
/etc/php5/conf.d/zend_extensions_psa.ini:extension=openssl.dll
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/zend_extensions_psa.ini:extension=openssl.dll
```

Comment: Let's see `grep -ir ssl /etc/php*`

Comment: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/zend_extensions_psa.ini:extension=openssl.dll
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/zend_extensions_psa.ini:extension=openssl.dll
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.saved_by_psa.08.03;20:24:;extension=openssl.dll       ; moved to conf.d/zend_extensions_psa.ini by Plesk
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:;extension=openssl.dll        ; moved to conf.d/zend_extensions_psa.ini by Plesk
/etc/php5/conf.d/zend_extensions_psa.ini:extension=openssl.dll
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/zend_extensions_psa.ini:extension=openssl.dll

Answer (score 1):

So you've got four copies of `zend_extensions_psa.ini` and all of them are trying to load this nonexistent file. Edit them all, delete or comment out the lines mentioning `openssl.dll`, and all should be well.

The Debian package management system treats your modifications to configuration files with great respect. It doesn't undo them when you upgrade or reinstall a package unless you remove the the package with `dpkg --purge` or install the new one with `--force-confnew`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have something like this in your PHP configuration (`php.ini` maybe):

```
extension_dir=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/
```

and then

```
extension=openssl.dll
```

And it could cause a problem because there is no file like that in a given path. This could be caused by manually copying extensions and/or different extensions installers.